# OpenGL Render To Texture (To screen) blank

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, render

I'm drawing a lot of points to the screen, and I am trying to get them to render to a texture for post processing before then rendering the texture back to the screen. Currently I'm trying to just pass through and get the texture rendering but it appears to be rendering nothing.

My fragment shader works (without render to texture - used bellow in mEllipseTextureProgram) and the only change I have made is to include

```
out vec3 color;
```

to render to the texture itself (and obviously change to color= rather than gl_FragColor=). The second program referenced below (mScreenProgram) is as follows:

Vertex Shader:

```
    #version 330 compatibility
    in vec2 vUV;

    out vec2 UV;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = gl_Vertex;
        UV = vUV;
    }
```

Fragment Shader:

```
    #version 330 core

    in vec2 UV;

    out vec3 color;

    uniform sampler2D renderedTexture;

    void main(){
        color = texture( renderedTexture, UV ).xyz; 
    }
```

I set up my render to texture **stuff** like this:

```
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &mGaussianFrameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, mGaussianFrameBuffer);
    glGenTextures(1, &mGaussianRenderTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mGaussianRenderTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 
                        1024,
                        768, 
                        0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                        NULL); 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, mGaussianRenderTexture, 0);
    glGenTextures(1, &mGaussianDepthBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mGaussianDepthBuffer);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 
                        1024,
                        768, 
                        0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT,
                        NULL); 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, mGaussianDepthBuffer, 0);
```

which returns a successful GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE.

Here are the three concerning rendering functions:

```
    void Draw()
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        //gluPerspective(45, 1024.0/768.0, 3.0, 20000);
        perspectiveGL(45, 1024.0/768.0, 1.0, 20000);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glPushMatrix();
        gluLookAt(cameraData[0],cameraData[1], cameraData[2],
                  cameraData[3],cameraData[4], cameraData[5],
                  0,1,0);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClearColor( 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.9f, 0.0f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  

        // OTHER STUFF POTENTIALLY DRAW HERE IN DIFFERENT WAYS

        glUseProgram(mEllipseTextureProgram);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, mGaussianFrameBuffer);
        GLuint attachments[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
        glDrawBuffers(1, attachments);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        DrawEllipseToTexture();
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glUseProgram(mScreenProgram);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        DrawTextureToScreen();
    }

    void DrawEllipseToTexture()
    {
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVBO);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);

        glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE);

        glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mBMP);
        glProgramUniform1i(mEllipseTextureProgram, mTextureLocation, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mUV);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLocation);
        glVertexAttribPointer(mTexCoordLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mSpacial);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(mSpacialLocation);
        glVertexAttribPointer(mSpacialLocation, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mNormals);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalLocation);
        glVertexAttribPointer(mNormalLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVerticalSpat);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(mMajorLocation);
        glVertexAttribPointer(mMajorLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mHorizontalSpat);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(mMinorLocation);
        glVertexAttribPointer(mMinorLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
        glEnable( GL_BLEND );

        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, mNumberPoints);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(mSpacialLocation);
        glDisable(GL_POINT_SPRITE);
        glDisable( GL_POINT_SMOOTH );
        glDisable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 
    }

    void DrawTextureToScreen()
    {
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 

        glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mGaussianRenderTexture);
        glProgramUniform1i(mScreenProgram, mGaussianTextureLocation, 0);

        GLfloat vertices[] = { -1, -1, 2,
                               1, -1, 2,
                               1, 1, 2,
                               -1, 1, 2 };
        GLfloat uv[] = { 0, 0,
                        1, 0,
                        1, 1,
                        0, 1,};

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(mGaussianUV);
        glVertexAttribPointer(mGaussianUV, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, uv);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 4);

        glDisable ( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what was wrong with my solution above (to which I tried a lot of variations) - but following this tutorial got it working: [Tutorial](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `out vec4 color', I am not sure whether it will work after you setting your texture type is GL_RGBA and then return vec3 for each fragment.

And I didnt see you set glViewport() in your code which means there is no specify affine transformation to mapping the screen position (x,y) from NDC to Screen space. If you don't have a viewport during fbo render, that definitely gives you nothing.

I am same as you struggling in the similar situation. Read the functions you don't know from GL documentation instead of blog is a much better way to understand things correctly... 
: )